# Firewall without MAC address

Tags: firewall

I read in a [paper](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/Pubs/TechRpts/2008/EECS-2008-82.pdf) that some middleboxes like firewalls don't have a MAC address for security purposes. I couldn't confirm using Google search. Is this common practice? How is this done?

Answer (score 1):

If the sole purpose of your firewall is to inspect and discard packets, there is no reason for it to have a MAC address. I mean, the whole point if a MAC address is to give the device a local (unique) identifier that other devices can use to talk to it. Since, in reality, they're only going to want to talk *through* it, it doesn't really need one.

In terms of implementation detail, the best one would be for it to pretend it's not there (which may violate standards). For example, take a packet. Inspect it, if it looks good, forward it on unmodified. If it looks bad, drop it like nothing happened.

Answer (score 1):

How is this done is easily answered. You only need a MAC if you need to be reachable as a destination via IP. Not for the simple task of echoing data (like a simple hub does, or like an unmanaged switch).

And as a firewall you do not need to echo/forward everything, just the ports which are opened.

Answer (score 1):

Host's interfaces can be grouped into the "bridge" - equivalent of the ethernet hub that simply retranslate everything incoming on the one interface to the others. All interfaces are works in so-called "promiscuous" mode and received every incoming packet despite of its destination MAC/IP-address at all. Host with bridge and packet filter inside called filtering bridge.

Filtering bridges was a common practice before vlans has been populated. They allow to seperate subnets in various ways and filter the traffic with complex rulesets. In fact, modern switches with vlans - are the same filtering bridges with the same logic inside.

Bridged promiscuous interfaces don't brodcast their MAC/IP over ARP so host become "stealth-host", invisible, insensible and inaccessible, manageable exclusively via console.

Comment: Can you please provide some articles/links which describe how to do that.

Comment: http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/transparent-bridging-firewall-devices